# How do I specify a class and an interface in a generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class which needs to lay out `View`s which implement `INavigationWrapper`.  If I define it like so:

```
public class NavigationStackLayout : Layout<T> where T : View, INavigationWrapper
```

then I need to specify T everywhere else.  If I define it like so:

```
public class NavigationStackLayout : Layout<View>
```

or

```
public class NavigationStackLayout : Layout<INavigationWrapper>
```

then the class' children are missing part of their type.  If I define it like so:

```
public class NavigationStackLayout : Layout<View : INavigationWrapper>
```

then that's a syntax error.  How do I specify a class and an interface in a generic parameter, without needing to specify a particular subclass?

UPDATE:

To be clear, I don't own `Layout<T>`, so I can't just add generic methods to my non-generic class; I need to use `Layout<T>`'s existing methods.  I know they'll work, because the constraint on `Layout<T>` is `where T : View`.

I'm looking for a solution which will make the following work:

```
class View1 : View, INavigationWrapper {}
class View2 : ContentView, INavigationWrapper {} // ContentView is a subclass of View
class View3 : View

var stack = new NavigationStackLayout();
stack.Add(new View1()); // this works
stack.Add(new View2()); // this also works
stack.Add(new View3()); // this fails at compile time
```

Comment: Does `View` already implement `INavigationWrapper` ? If not, then yes you need the subtype, to access members from both types. Or you can create a base class derived of `View` which implements `INavigationWrapper` which your `View` subclasses are derived from.

Comment: No, `View` doesn't.  I don't have a particular subtype in mind, I just want to be able to add any `View` which implements `INavigationWrapper`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "then I need to specify T everywhere else" - what is your complaint here? What are you trying to avoid?

Comment: *I just want to be able to add any View which implements INavigationWrapper* But that is exactly what your constraint says, that a type must implement both `View` and `INavigationWrapper`.

Comment: Are you looking for an abstract class to implement base functionality, then you can inherit from abstract. Either way all inherited interfaces will need their methods fully implemented by the time you reach concrete class

Comment: Or what about `public class NavigationStackLayout<T> : Layout<T> where T : View, INavigationWrapper`

Comment: @Joe same problem - I'd need to specify T in advance

Comment: What I want is to create a single, non-generic class that will allow any view to be added to it so long as it conforms to `INavigationWrapper`.  I don't want to create a new base class for views and I don't want to create a generic class.

Comment: @Simon T will need to be specified at some point before implementing as a concrete class. This looks very similar to repository pattern, there your base abstract class and interface take an anonymous type but easy repository interface which derives from the base specify their type at inheritance. Then the concrete class can implement an interface for each repository. You simply can't construct a concrete class as T.

Comment: Or you might be able to add the type to your constructor and construct based on reflected type at runtime. I still don't understand what you are trying to do sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are okay with only putting a single class into each `NavigationStackLayout` objects you could go the generic route and add a static method on a separate non-generic class that creates an instance in a generic way and allows you to avoid having to name the generic parameter.

Alternatively pick a concrete class since overly generic code isn't worth that much of a hassle.

As a final option you could reimplement all the functions as being generic and constraining the type, just pick one type or the other for your underlying storage and cast it when you take it out.

The fundamental problem is that you need a type to fill in a generic parameter. You need to either punt and ask someone else to make a choice (generic) or select a single type that exists (so either `View` or `INavigationWrapper`).

Note that no matter what you do if you want the following types to coexist in a single layout you are going to have bend the rules on type safety a little (such as pick an arbitrary base class for storage).

```
class View1 : View, INavigationWrapper
class View2 : View, INavigationWrapper
```

Comment: Why would I need to bend the rules?  I'm adding a constraint, not allowing anything new.

Comment: @Simon: What single type are you referring to? If you can name it then you can have type safety for it. C# doesn't have any form of constraints except generic constraints.